# How much spaces fit onto a computercraft computer screen? (1.7.10)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I am making a computercraft arcade for my friends and I would like to replicate crossy road. My questions is about computer screen (on computer item id: 1586:16384 in dw20 modpack).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I did not search the wiki enough! It is 51 pixels horizontaly and 19 pixels verticaly. This does not differ over the computer types.

Comment: To get the size of the computer screen properly, use `term.getSize()`. Turtle and pocket computer screens have different dimensions